# Use Value If Exists Else Use Default Value MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

**Current Tools**: Using Java to communicate with MySQL

I tried doing a search multiple times and ended up with this, but it didn't help me solve my problem. [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20use%20default%20value%20java%20mysql&gws_rd=ssl#q=use%20default%20value%20setInt%20mysql)

I'm currently writing some query statements to try to save some information about my game objects to a database. I wanted to save the object's ID number if it wasn't 0, and to use the auto increment function otherwise if it *was* 0. For an example:

```
// (?,?) = (itemid, amount)
// itemid -> primary key and auto increment. 

PreparedStatement ps = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO items (?,?)");
ps.setInt(1, item.id() == 0 ? >>>>DEFAULT<<<< : item.id());
ps.setInt(2, item.quantity());
```

The issue of course is that the way I'm doing isn't the correct way to tell MySQL to auto increment instead. Is there a way to do so? Also, the reason why I'm purposely inserting an ID in even though it's auto-increment is that I wrote a method previously that allowed me to save the original state of an item (thus preserving its stats). Upon loading this item, I want to be able to replace the current item and its stats with the newly loaded one.

**Main Problem**: Want to be able to insert a value if a condition is satisfied, otherwise use the auto-increment for primary key if possible. If there is something wrong with my approach, I'm open ears. Currently a beginner at databases!

Comment: I would probably discourage this, I'd have a "key" which was always incremented and then have a separate object id which you can manipulate, the point of auto incrementing keys is, you shouldn't care about them. You're really hell bent on this, you should then have a look at "sequences", basically, if the `id` is `0`, you will need to query the next value from the "sequence" you've setup which is associated with your items table

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

As per MySQL suggestion, if you insert 0 into the id column, that column will automatically generate a sequence number.

Here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Note that you should set the column (id) to AUTO-INCREMENT when the table is created. The auto increment will start at 1 so I you insert 0 the next max number will be inserted.

```
PreparedStatement ps = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO item(id, quantity) VALUES(?,?)");
ps.setInt(1, item.id());
ps.setInt(2, item.quantity());
```

Comment: It would be better to insert `NULL`, not 0, because the sql_mode [`NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero), if enabled, will assume you really wanted to insert the 0, but `NULL` always works as expected.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are right. Although I am assuming that  NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO is set by default. Besides the OP stated that the id column is a primary key. So NULL is not allow to be inserted.

Comment: I'm afraid you miss the point on two fronts.  You can *always* insert `NULL` into an auto increment primary key column because `NULL` ("the absence of a value") *by definition* means "assign the next auto increment value here" when the column is PK+AI. What do you think an insert statement inserts into columns not explicitly mentioned? `NULL`.  On the other hand, inserting `0` is the hacky, wacky, "also usually works" solution, but requires `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` to be *disabled*.  Click the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
PreparedStatement ps = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO items (?,?)");
ps.setInt(1, (item.id() == 0 ? 0 : item.id()));
ps.setInt(2, item.quantity());
```